# Access Form to open form or report depending on what's in table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a combobox showing all my reports.  Some of my reports have a lookup form that needs to be filled in to get the correct data.  Example, I open a form, and pick a year, and then the report opens for that year.

The values from the combobox come from a table that has the report name and what to run to bring up form or report - some are OpenForm and others are OpenReport.  I did put the whole command in this field - DoCmd.Open(report or form).  How can I get this to run?

Here is my code so far with ??? by what I don't get:

```
    If Not IsNull(ComboReports) And ComboReports <> "" Then

    Dim rep As Variant
    rep = DLookup("[ReportOpenCommand]", "tblCodesReports", "ReportAccessName = " & Me.ComboReports)
    DoCmd.???? rep

Else

    MsgBox ("You Must First Select a Report To Print!")
    ComboReports.SetFocus

End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do all your forms and reports start with frm or rpt (or something similiar?)

Comment: Gene - yes frm and rpt.

Comment: Hans - tblCodesReports - 3 fields - ReportAccessName, ReportName, ReportOpenCommand, and ReportID.  All are Text fields,except Report ID which is an Integer.  ReportAccessName is the Access report name, ReportName is the display name, ReportOpenCommand is where I have the docmd.open??, and ReportID is just an ID.

Comment: us if statement. If (LEFT(rep,3) = "frm") THEN docmd.openform rep elseif left(rep,3) = "rpt" then docmd.openreport rep end if

Comment: After you asked if they started with frm or rpt, I figured it out!  Something so simple, and I didn't think about it.  That's why I love you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get it to run by storing the whole command in the field. You have to store parameters.

**Solution A: Use Fields**

Create fields for ObjectName, ObjectType, and FriendlyTitle. Use these to select and run the report. These can be directly loaded into the combobox for ease of use:

**tblCodesReports:**

```
+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|  ReportId  | ObjectName | ObjectType | FriendlyTitle |
+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| AutoNumber | Text       | Long       | Text          |
+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

**Combobox:**

- Row Source: SELECT ReportId,FriendlyTitle,ObjectName,ObjectType FROM tblCodesReports ORDER BY FriendlyTitle
- Column Count: 4
- Column Widths: 0;2;0;0
- Bound Column: 1

**Code**

```
Dim sName As String
Dim eType As Access.AcObjectType

With ComboReports

    sName = .Column(2, .ListIndex)
    eType = .Column(3, .ListIndex)

    Select Case eType
        Case acForm
            DoCmd.OpenForm sName
        Case acReport
            DoCmd.OpenReport sName 
    End If

End With
```

**Solution B: Use Report.Open**

- Only use Report Names in your table
- Open the Forms in the Report_Open Event Handler to supply parameters

see: [Difference between Form.Open and Form.Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711924/difference-between-the-on-open-event-and-the-on-load-event-for-a-data-entry/31712800#31712800)